# Playing sound on kindle fire

Tags: kindle, kindle-fire

the problem is that when trying to play music he plays is not always the case. At the same time the log is issued the following lines

(sound not playing)

```
04-20 10:59:44.944: WARN/ASFDummyExtractor(11743): ASF parser is not available
04-20 10:59:44.944: ERROR/MPEG4Extractor(11743): both mdat,ftyp not found
```

(sound playing)

```
04-20 11:07:50.335: WARN/ASFDummyExtractor(11743): ASF parser is not available
04-20 11:07:50.342: ERROR/MPEG4Extractor(11743): both mdat,ftyp not found
04-20 11:07:50.358: DEBUG/AudioResampler(11743): forcing AudioResampler quality to 2
04-20 11:07:50.358: DEBUG/Omap4ALSA(11743): open called for devices 00000002 in mode 0 
channels 00000000...
04-20 11:07:50.366: INFO/Omap4ALSA(11743): Using ping-pong!
04-20 11:07:50.366: INFO/Omap4ALSA(11743): Buffer size: 4096
04-20 11:07:50.366: INFO/Omap4ALSA(11743): Latency: 92879
04-20 11:07:50.428: INFO/Omap4ALSA(11743): Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK device 'plughw:0,0'
04-20 11:07:50.428: ERROR/AudioHardwareALSA(11743): RE-OPEN AFTER STANDBY:: took 69 msecs
```

there is no problem on other android devices (samsung tablet ...)

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, R.raw.buttonclick);
if (mp != null)
mp.start();
```

someone faced with this problem?
use *.ogg sound file

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue on a kindle fire, with my app. I'm testing it right now. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I found out that the not available stuff is due to the inner workings of the media player on the kindle. It scans first for asf file, then mp4, and gives that error log if the file is not of that type. On my device it plays all files nicely, but I have some issues with strange noises after playing lots of sounds. Unrelated I think.